# How to set last recorded value to spinner dropdown?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

```
String Food;
String[] FoodArray;
Spinner spinFood;
spinFood= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin_food);
FoodArray=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.carray);
spinFood.setAdapter(new 
CustomSpinnerAdapter(ChildActivity.this,R.layout.activity_child,FoodArray));

spinFood.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() 
{
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
        position, long id) {

            if(position==1){
                Food=getString(R.string.textYes);
            }
            else if (position==2){
                Food=getString(R.string.textNo);
            }
            else {
               Food="0";
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

i tried a lot  but didn't get the answer,
 please help me.

the spinner should be set to a last recorded value which comes from the database, by default.

Comment: You say several times that you tried a lot, but I don't actually see any SQLite code in there.  If you wanted the latest record, and your table had a timestamp column, you could easily do a `LIMIT 1` query ordering descending on that timestamp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 String compareValue;
                ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinFood.setAdapter(new CustomSpinnerAdapter(
                        getApplicationContext().this, R.layout.yourlayout,
                        compareValue));
                if (!compareValue.equals(null)) {
                    int spinnerPosition = adapter.getPosition(compareValue);
                    spinFood.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
                }
```

take your last recorded value i.e compareValue from sqlite database and set that value to ArrayAdapter and check for the null condition.

Comment: Please add some explanatory text to your answer.

Comment: take your last recorded value i.e compareValue from sqlite database and set that value to ArrayAdapter and check for the null condition.

Comment: Please edit your answer and add the text in connection to your answer. Please fix also the indenting of the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `spinner.setSelection()` method to record your last transaction